# PHP - Removing Duplicate Punctuation?

Tags: php

Suppose you have the following string: `Hello... how are you!!?? I'm bored!!`

I want back-to-back punctuation to be removed wherever possible, and for question marks to be retained in the event of a situation similar to "!?". The filtered string should appear as follows:

`Hello. how are you? I'm bored!`

Best answer goes to the most concise solution that solves this problem. I expect regular expressions will be the best way to go about solving this, but my knowledge of regular expressions is very, very limited at best, and I have no idea how to go about solving this. I'm more than fine with non-regex solutions, however! An explanation of any code you provide--unless devilishly simple--would also be nice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('~[?!]{2,}~', '?', preg_replace('~([.,!?])(\\1+)~', '\\1', $str));
```

or in one `preg_replace` call (thanks to Alix Axel)

```
$str = preg_replace(array('~([.,!?])(\\1+)~', '~[?!]{2,}~'), array('\\1', '?'), $str);
```

Just enumerate all the punctuation you care of in the braces

**UPD**: to handle `!?` just nest it with another regular expression

Explanation of what it all means:

```
preg_replace('~([.,!?])(\\1+)~', '\\1', $str)
```

The expression `([.,!?])(\\1+)` means - find any of `.,!?` only if it is preceded by at least one the same character `\\1+`, where `\\1` - is reference to the previous match, and `+` is `at least one`.

And replace all of this with only single char.

The outer expression `[?!]{2,}` means `find all ? or ! if they are at least 2 in a row` and replace it with `?`

Comment: I don't believe this solution takes into account the issue with question marks. EDIT--actually, I just tested this, and it doesn't work at all. :/

Comment: @Nathanael Shermett: oh, so `!?` should always lead to `?`? And what about `?!`?

Comment: I just tested your new code, it works perfectly! Can you explain how it works, though? I don't get it, haha.

Comment: Do you really need two calls? Can't you just do `$str = preg_replace(array('~([.,!?])(\\1+)~', '~[?!]{2,}~'), array('$1', '?'), $str);`?

Comment: FYI, preg functions are VERY slow. I would be interested to see if my solution is faster. But not interested enough to test it myself.

Comment: @Buttle Butkus: you're overdramatizing. The speed makes sense **only** if he has megabytes of texts and performs thousands of such transrformations a second. In all other cases - it doesn't really matter

Comment: Yeah, this is only for fixing one string every time the script is run. Your solution is clever, though!

Answer (score 1):

you can use preg_replace:

```
$a="Hello... how are you!!?? Im bored!!!!!!"; echo preg_replace("/([.!?])+/iS","$1",$a);

=> Hello. how are you? Im bored!
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Can you explain how, though? :)

Comment: @Nathanael Shermett: it would fail on `?!`

Comment: what is expect for !!?? case? just !? -- the original question show only ? in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Hello... how are you!!?? I'm bored!!"
$new_string = $string;
foreach(array('.',',','?','!') as $value) {
  $i = ;
  do {
    $prev_string = $new_string;
    $string = str_replace($value . $value,$value,$string;
    $i++;
  } while ($string !== $prev_string && $i<100)
}
```

That gets rid of duplicates but not ?!?.

I think this second solution will work, keeping the FIRST of your "bad_chars".
If you want to keep the LAST one, there are solutions to that as well.

```
<?php
$string = str_split($string);
$new_string = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($string as $key => $char) {
    echo 'Processing: ' . $char . '<br />';
    $prev_key = $key - 1;
    $prev_char = $string[$prev_key];
  if($i!== 0) {
    if(in_array($char,$bad_chars) && in_array($prev_char,$bad_chars) ) {
      // do nothing
    } else {
      $new_string[] = $char;
    }
  } else {
    $prev_char = $char;
    $new_string[] = $prev_char;
  }
  $i++;
}
$string = implode('',$string);
$new_string = implode('',$new_string);
?><br />

<?php echo $string; ?><br />
<?php echo $new_string; ?><br />
```

Comment: Embrace regular expressions, don't fight'em!

Comment: A small note: this only would work with single-byte character sets, while solution with regexes could be fixed in one keystroke

Comment: I edited my second solution. Now perhaps it is multibyte safe? Array traversal is very fast, whereas regex is very slow. I do use regex for getting data out of complex strings, but I don't know if it makes sense for this simple problem. I wonder what word processors use.

Comment: "Array traversal is very fast, whereas regex is very slow" --- could you please prove that?

Comment: Arrays use fixed memory addresses. It is common knowledge that arrays are very fast. It is also common knowledge that regex is slow. But perhaps that common knowledge is wrong. Perhaps I will set up a test with a large number of strings and see if those statements are really true.