# How can I replace all duplicate punctuation with single punctuation in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Is there an efficient way to replace all duplicate non-alphanumeric characters with single characters?

This question forces one to be explicit about the punctuation characters:

[PHP - Removing Duplicate Punctuation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545303/php-removing-duplicate-punctuation)

Like so:

```
$str = preg_replace('~[?!]{2,}~', '?', preg_replace('~([.,!?])(\\1+)~', '\\1', $str));
```

Is it possible to achieve the same result but for ALL non-alphanumeric characters without explicitly referencing them by name?

Here's a use case:

```
Hello...  how   are you!!??  I''m bored!!----!!!&&&&&^^^^%%%(()))((<<<<<
```

to

```
Hello. how are you!? I'm bored!-!&^%()(<
```

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately the above cuts too deep in one use case: `http://`. How can one keep double `/` for urls (or simply when they follow `:`), but not allow regular repeat `/` or even more than 2 `/` after a `:`.  Here is a single use case:

```
My ////favorite//// site is http://///example.com!!!!!!!
```

becomes:

```
My /favorite/ site is http://example.com!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
$str = preg_replace('~((?<!:)[^\p{L}\p{N}])\1+~u', '$1', $str);
//=> Hello. how are you!? I'm bored!-!&^%()(<
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rP2jP9/2)

- `[^\p{L}\p{N}]` - Match anything but unicode alphanumeric character
- `(?<!:)` - Match only if not precede by `:` to take care of `http://...`
- `([^\p{L}\p{N}])` - Capture above in a group #1 for back-reference
- `\1+` - Match one or more of captured group #1, thus making sure 2 or more of same non-alphanumeric is matched
- Replace it by `$1` i.e. the captured non-alphanumeric character

Comment: Awesome work @anubhava. Unfortunately I cut a bit too deep on one use case: http://.  Is it possible to exclude this use case (`://`), while still replacing this use case: (`hello////////there!`)? See revised question above for further clarification. Thanks again for getting me this far.